# Input multiple date from a calendar (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a leave management app, and I need to input multiple date into a field from calendar (jquery ui datepicker or something like that).

I've tried `gem 'multi-dates-picker-rails'`, but it's not working.

Would you give a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show some of your code? How you store dates, attempt with multi-dates-picker, and controller method?

Comment: @KrzysztofWitczak i've solved this problem with the below solution of Nataraja B :D Anyway, thanks you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below jquery library file

http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/

**Javascript**

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js

**CSS**

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css

include these file into assets

In html

```
<%= text_field_tag :route_dates, nil, class: "gui-input", placeholder: "Select date" %>
```

coffescript

```
date = new Date()
$('#route_dates').multiDatesPicker
  addDates: [date, date]
  dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. You saved my day bro!